# if-else statements and 2d arrays

Tags: java, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I am writing a method that checks to see if certain moves of a checkers game are valid by returning true or false. My code works fine when I want to move diagonally (not jumping). However, when I try to see if my piece can jump across another piece, nothing gets returned (no false, no true, no error message, just blank). I have a `setLocation` method that takes three parameters of the checkers board column, row, and piece color which places a checkers piece at the said location on the board.

How can I get my code to return true or false if I have pieces on the board set and I want to see if a piece can jump over an opposing color piece? curRow and curCol are just the current row and column that the piece is at. destRow and destCol are the destination that I want my piece to go to.

Here's my code:

```
if (board[curCol][curRow].equals(Piece.WHITE)){
    boolean valid=false;
    if ((curRow+1==destRow&&curCol+1==destCol)&&board[destRow][destCol].equals(Piece.NONE)){
        valid=true;
    }else if ((curRow+1==destRow&&curCol-1==destCol)&&board[destRow][destCol].equals(Piece.NONE)){
        valid=true;
    //jumps up right over piece 
    }else if ((curRow+2==destRow&&curCol+2==destCol)&&board[destRow-1][destCol-1].equals(Piece.BLACK)){
        valid=true;
    //jumps up left over piece
    else if ((curRow+2==destRow&&curCol-2==destCol)&&(board[destRow-1][destCol+1].equals(Piece.BLACK))){
        valid=true;
    }else{
        return valid;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: If the condition at the top of the `if` statement is `true`, the code will always return something or throw an exception.  So either the condition at the top is false, or it's throwing an exception and you missed it, or it's returning something but you missed it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Java can't return "blanks".  If your method (which you don't show the declaration of) is a boolean method, it MUST return a boolean.

Why not try something like this:

```
private static board Peice[][] = new Peice[][]

private enum Peice{
  BLACK(-1, false),
  BLACK_CROWN(-1, true),
  WHITE(1, false),
  WHITE_CROWN(1, true)

  private int direction;
  private boolean crowned;

  public Peice(int direction, boolean crowned){
    this.direction = direction;
    this.crowned = crowned;
  }

  public boolean isLegal(int curRow, int curCol, int destRow, int destCol){
    //not valid if the spot is occupied or if the  move isn't the same distance each way
    if (board[destRow, destCol] != null) || ((Math.abs(destRow - CurRow) != (Math.abs(destCol - curCol)){
      return false;
    }

    if (abs(destRows - curRows) == 1){
      return (destRow - curRow == direction) || crowned;
    } else if (abs(destRows-curRows) == 2){
      return takeMove(curRow, curCol, destRow, destCol);
    // anything but 1 or 2 moves diagonal is never ok.
    } else{
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean takeMove(int curRow, int curCol, int destRow, int destCol)
    if (!isOpponent(board[(curRow + destRow)/2, (curCol + destCol)/2])){
      return false;
    }
    return (destRow - curRow) * direction > 0 || crowned;
  }

  private boolean isOpponent(Peice other){
    return other.direction != this.direction
  }
}
```